Can't switch Wildfly datasource to read only
Using Java 8, Spring 2.1.3, Wildfly 10.1.0, MySQL 8.0.33 and AWS advanced JDBC wrapper 2.3.9.
I can't reach my aws RDS reader instance at all when a transaction is indicated as “readOnly”.
There's no call for switchConnectionIfRequired, as if the plugin wasn't listening to the transactional annotation and its readOnly property.
I'm expecting my Wildfly datasource to switch in read only mode when using @transactional(readOnly=true)
I've built a minimal example that reproduce the issue here
Following JPA/Hibernate code source, I don’t see any reason that the read only flag to not be raised.
And from my understanding of wildfly/spring architecture, JTA would be the last reason why it doesn’t propagate the flag.
At this point, I've no idea if this is a Wildfly JTA limitation or a missing configuration. Any idea ?
